# Class property not instantiated before constructor sets it - bad?

Tags: php, oop

By accident, I noticed that the below works in PHP:

```
class
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Notice that this was not declared before use
        $this->not_declared = "Hello";
    }

    public function display()
    {
        echo $this->not_declared; // Outputs "Hello"
    }
}
```

Is it bad practice? I was always under the impression that properties must be declared before use, like this:

```
class
{
    private $not_declared = "";

    public function __construct()
    {
        // In this case, it was declared above
        $this->not_declared = "Hello";
    }

    public function display()
    {
        echo $this->not_declared; // Outputs "Hello"
    }
}
```

Comment: PHP is a dynamic language. So yes, it is a good practice to declare properties, but no, you don't have to, you can add them dynamically too. Declaring them has a wide range of advantages: readability, IDE autocompletion, type hinting, ...

Comment: What @arkascha is saying, when you declare a property that has not been defined by its class or any parent class, the property is "created" (assigned) automatically and its scope is set public.